# Import Visual Studio syntax highlighting in Notepad++

Tags: visual-studio, notepad++

Is there any way to import Visual Studio syntax highlighting in Notepad++? I need it for HTML,PHP,JavaScript syntax highlighting

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in syntax highlighting Notepad++ has for these languages?

Comment: This is more a question for superuser

Comment: @delnan I don't like it, it is not easily distinguishable when working with all three languages

Comment: @LifeH2O: The colors can be adjusted.

Comment: I just want the same color scheme as that of visual studio, do you know how to 'translate' the color scheme xml file of visual studio? http://studiostyl.es/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

- Close Notepad++
- Download [Notepad++ Visual Studio Theme](https://web.archive.org/web/20121012070534/http://shilony.net/files/Notepad++%20Visual%20Studio%20Theme.zip)
- Extract the files to  `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\themes` then start Notepad++ (create themes folder if it does not exist)
- In the menu bar, open **Settings→Style Configurator...**
- Click the **Select theme** dropdown and select the **Visual Studio** theme.
- Click **Save & Close button**.

Information about theme can be found [on archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20130702221611/http://www.shilony.net/2012/09/02/notepad-visual-studio-theme).

Comment: Note that this theme is the Light version, not Dark.

Comment: I guess that there is no "Dark" theme in Visual Studio .NET 2003, it might have appeared in later versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: True. The light/dark theme "out of the box" feature first appeared in Visual Studio 2012

Comment: @Philippe I put together a replica of the dark theme [here](https://github.com/SeanCline/Npp-VS2012-Dark/).

Comment: Hi Sean, great job with that theme but there is something you need to change for this kind of syntax coloring i.e; DataTable dtTable where "DataTable" suppose to be in Green color instead of White.

Comment: this one is a dark style: https://github.com/Ludomancer/VS2015-Dark-Npp

Comment: just wanted to point out the op is asking for syntax highlighting not themes

Comment: @ZackOfAllTrades Isn't syntax highlighting (i.e. not recognition of types of tags / keywords / number, but coloring already recognized items) in Notepad++ implemented via themes?

Comment: Lol @ the link being by the waybackmachine. +1!

Answer (score 4):

Notepad++ only supports its own highlighting of plain text.  Try pasting it into something that normally edits rich text like Word.

Comment: All the languages OP mentioned are written in plain text files.

Comment: If you copy from Visual Studio and paste into Word, it preserves the syntax highlighting, which is what I meant.  I was assuming that he wanted to preserve the highlighting for something like documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You have this version on GitHub :
https://github.com/SeanCline/Npp-VS2012-Dark

Comment: And here is a VS2015 port of that above Dark Theme:  https://github.com/Nidre/VS2015-Dark-Npp

Answer (score 2):

Although You can't directly **"import"** the syntax highlighting style of Visual Studio. you can set up your own **custom highlighting** styles. Or edit the existing ones.

**Edit:**

There are many resources on-line on how to create/edit custom Syntax Highlighting.

Here is one:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/25/creating-a-user-defined-language-in-notepad.aspx

Comment: How to convert/translate the coloring of visual studio syntax highlighting xml files from http://studiostyl.es/

Answer (score 1):

- Close Notepad++
- Download Notepad++ Visual Studio Theme "VS2019-Dark.xml" **https://github.com/hellon8/VS2019-Dark-Npp**
- Extract the files to C:\Program Files\Notepad++\themes then start Notepad++ (create themes folder if it does not exist)
- In the menu bar, open Settings→Style Configurator vs2019-Dark...
  [image]
- Click the Select theme dropdown and select the Visual Studio theme.
- Click Save & Close button.

Answer (score 0):

**https://github.com/60ss/Npp-1-Dark**

Theme Installation:

- Download Npp-1-Dark.xml.
- Run Notepad++ As administrator.
- Open Setting -> Import -> Import style theme(s).
- Choose Npp-1-Dark.xml.
- Open Settings -> Style Configurator and Select theme Npp-1-Dark.
- Click Save & Close.

Sass Syntax Highlighting Installation:

- Download Npp-1-Dark-Sass.xml.
- Open Language -> Define your language....
- Click Import and Choose Npp-1-Dark-Sass.xml.
- Click Open.
- Restart Notepad++.

Comment: Why do you create two answers? You should modify your previous answer.